# Structure of handles of GUIs MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have three GUIs in MATLAB. The tag of each of them is `'P0'`, `'P1'` and `'P2'`. I would like to put the handles of all three GUIs in a structure and be able to get to this structure from any of three GUIs and update the values in it. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked at `getappdata` and `setappdata`?

Comment: It may be worth creating a `handle` class that you store your data in and then you can store a handle to it with `guidata` and modify it from either GUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of options on how to do this. One way would be to use the root graphics object along with `setappdata` and `getappdata` to store and retrieve values.

```
fig0 = findall(0, 'tag', 'P0');
fig1 = findall(0, 'tag', 'P1');
fig2 = findall(0, 'tag', 'P2');

% Combine the GUIdata into a single struct
handles.P0 = guidata(fig0);
handles.P1 = guidata(fig1);
handles.P2 = guidata(fig2);

% Store this struct in the root object where ALL GUIs can access it
setappdata(0, 'myappdata', handles);
```

Then from within your callback, you'd simply fetch this struct and use it directly

```
function mycallback(hObject, evnt, ~)
    % Ignore the handles that is passed in and use your own
    handles = getappdata(0, 'myappdata');

    % Now if you modify it, you MUST save it again
    handles.P0.value = 1;

    setappdata(0, 'myappdata', handles)
end
```

Another option is to use a [`handle` class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) to store your values and then you can store a *reference* to this handle class within the `handles` struct of each GUI. When you make changes to this struct, the changes will be reflected in all GUIs.

An easy way to do this would be to use [`structobj`](https://github.com/suever/structobj) (Disclaimer: I am the developer) which will convert any `struct` into a `handle` object.

```
% Create an object that looks like a struct but is a handle class and fill it with the 
% handles struct from each GUI
handles = structobj(guidata(fig0));
update(handles, guidata(fig1));
update(handles, guidata(fig2));

% Now store this in the guidata of each figure
guidata([fig0, fig1, fig2], handles)
```

Since we stored a thing within the `guidata` of the figure, it will automatically be passed to your callback via the standard `handles` input argument. So now your callback would look something like:

```
function mycallback(hObject, evnt, handles)
    % Access the data you had stored
    old_thing = handles.your_thing;

    % Update the value (changes will propagate across ALL GUIs)
    handles.your_thing = 2;
end
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can have multiple instances of your three GUIs running at the same time and the data will not interfere with each other.